# Using qemu to boot OpenSUSE (or any other OS) with custom kernel?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system, qemu

[Duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89985/using-qemu-to-boot-opensuse-or-any-other-os-with-custom-kernel); 
Could not find an answer, so posting here.

I want to run OpenSUSE as guest with a custom kernel image which is on my host machine. I'm trying:

`$ qemu-system-x86_64 -hda opensuse.img -m 512 -kernel
    ~/kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -initrd 
    ~/kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/initrd.img -boot c`

But it boots into BusyBox instead. Using uname -a shows Linux (none). Also, using `-append "root=/dev/sda"` (as suggested on the link above) does not seem to work. How do I tell the kernel image to boot with OpenSUSE?

I have OpenSUSE installed into opensuse.img, and:

`$ qemu-system-x86_64 -hda opensuse.img -m 512 -boot c`

boots it with the stock kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Most virtual machines are booted from a disk image or an ISO file, but KVM can directly load a Linux kernel into memory skipping the bootloader. This means you don't need an image file containing the kernel and boot files. Instead, you can run a kernel directly like this:

qemu-kvm -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage -initrd initramfs.gz -append "console=ttyS0" -nographic

These flags directly load a kernel and initramfs from the host filesystem without the need to generate a disk image or configure a bootloader.

The optional -initrd flag loads an initramfs for the kernel to use as the root filesystem.

The -append flags adds kernel parameters and can be used to enable the serial console.

The -nographic option restricts the virtual machine to just a serial console and therefore keeps all test kernel output in your terminal rather than in a graphical window.

Take a look in the below link. It has lot more info [thanks to the Guy who wrote all that]
http://blog.vmsplice.net/2011/02/near-instant-kernel-development-cycle.html

Comment: Hey! This is what I'm doing to run just the kernel right now. But I want the it to run with some other OS too (like openSUSE or debian). Is it possible with qemu?

Comment: My guess is that, if you give proper input options to the kernel with '-append' it should work. Can you check if you are able to mount your suse.img from the busybox shell and boot from there?

Answer (score 0):

Usually for arm architecture like raspberry pi or any board .

To boot with your custom kernel

`qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda 2013-05-25-wheezy-raspbian.img`

where -hda your suse.img here u have to find in which partition your rootfs present u can check

fdisk -l your image

if only one partition then pass /dev/sda or if its in 2nd /dev/sda2

I think no need of initrd image required here. usually it will mount main rootfs so no need when u boot it main rootfs.

So try this
`qemu-system-x86_64 -hda opensuse.img -m 512 -kernel ~/kernel/linux-git/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage  -append "root=/dev/sda" -boot c`

Note check exactly in which partition your rootfs is present then pass /dev/sda*

Im not sure you just try above one . Also you mention that `uname -a`

gives `linux none` This is bcoz while configuring your kernel you have to mention name otherwise it ll default take as none